# DOM's charset different from the displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, html, dom, character-encoding, google-chrome-extension

I'm facing a weird problem. The text inside the html has accents, e.g.:

```
<p>é</p>
```

It is displayed correctly in the screen (é), but the content inside the DOM instance does not accepts the accents. It is displaying a "?" character instead of the character with accent.

In my case, I'm injecting javascript code in the Kindle (http://read.amazon.com) using a chrome extension, but don't think it is really relevant as I can see the problem just using the chrome console.

A simplified version of the html structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <iframe id="KindleReaderIFrame">
            <html>
                <head>
                    ...
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
                    ...
                </head>
                <body>
                    ...
                    <iframe id="column_0_frame_0">
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <!-- Do not have the Content-Type meta tag -->
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <!-- Text with accents that I intend to get through DOM -->
                            </bady>
                        </html>
                    </iframe>
                    ...
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The text I want is inside the "column_0_frame_0" iframe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrames and encodings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270847/iframes-and-encodings)

Comment: I tested the situation described in the topic above, but the problems seem a little different. In the cited topic, in my test, the characters in the DOM and the displayed on screen have the same charset.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code, you  have not closed the body tag correctly, see below :

```
<iframe id="column_0_frame_0">
    <html>
       <head>
        <!-- Do not have the Content-Type meta tag -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Text with accents that I intend to get through DOM ->
        </bady>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Secondly, if you are loading your contents in iFrame or through AJAX, its not enough to set the character set in meta tag, sometimes it depends on the IDE which you used to create your code.

To check:

1. Open the same code in Notepad++
2. Save the contents using charset UTF-8 (default ANSI).
3. Run code on your local server without opening the file in any other IDE.

Now you will be able to render the accents correctly in DOM as well as screen.